# Question on formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column in SharePoint at the moment, it uses a formula to pull in a month name, number of holidays in the that month and then multiplied by 3. The formula I am using is:

```
IF([Month]=“August”,[Number of Days]*3)
```

This works fine, however if I also want to calculate month of June in same formula to give combined figure for August and June, can anyone help with formula I should use please?

Comment: Do you have the "figure" or no of days for both august month and june month in same list item/row or different list items/rows?

Comment: Yes both in same list @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP

Comment: I am not asking about same list. I am asking about same item/row/record.

Comment: My apologies. Yes same item/row/record @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP

Comment: Are there two different columns for August and June? Can you add more details how you want the combined figure? explain with some examples & data to understand it properly, thanks!

Comment: So I have a choice column to select ‘month’ and a separate column where I can input the number of days holiday. Each month I add will have its own row. I would like the combined figure to be August holiday + June Holiday *3 for example 5 days holiday in August + 5 days holiday in June *3 = 30 days holiday in total which would show in a separate column @GaneshSanap-MicrosoftMVP

Comment: As you are adding new row for each month, it is not same "item/row/record".  Hence, you will not be able to get the combined figure using SharePoint calculated column as column formula cannot read values from different rows (it can read column values from same item/row).

Comment: As Ganesh said, this cannot be achieved simply by using calculated columns from within the SharePoint list.
Power Automate and Power Apps are indeed better choices. You can add relevant tags to your posts, or you can search or post in discussions related to this issue there(https://powerusers.microsoft.com/).

Comment: @user107779, does my below response answers your question?

Comment: If yes, please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Answer (score 0):

As you are creating/adding new list item/row for each month (For example: June & August), you will not be able to get the combined figure using SharePoint calculated column.

SharePoint calculated column formulas cannot read values from different list items/rows, it can read column values from same item/row only - This is by design limitation of SharePoint calculated columns.

> You cannot reference a value in a row other than the current row.

**Microsoft Documentation Source**: [Introduction to SharePoint formulas and functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-sharepoint-formulas-and-functions-94e1b4cc-cd1c-49c2-80ec-90c9b9591f47#bm3)

You may need to use another way for your requirements like using scheduled (daily, etc.) Power automate flow to read items from SharePoint list and get the combined figure OR customize the list forms using Power Apps and calculate the combined figure using Power Apps formula/functions while saving/updating list items.